# How to capture a log message coming out of node JS spawn ffmpeg command

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to find the silent parts of an audio recording. This command does exactly what I want on my local machine.

> ffmpeg -i http://twf-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/DBC50460-9A5C-4174-9885-07337A582D58_1377839443598_tell.m4a -af silencedetect=n=-40dB:d=0.2 -f null -

It sends a bunch of messages to the command line including these last three which are the lines of data that I need. (for reference: [ffmpeg silencedetect docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect))

> [silencedetect @ 0x7feea040cf20] silence_start: 0.0321995
>
> [silencedetect @ 0x7feea040cf20] silence_end: 0.975238 | silence_duration: 0.943039
>
> [silencedetect @ 0x7feea040cf20] silence_start: 1.47184

I cannot figure out how to get that message out. Here is the nodejs code that is running. The only event that is triggered is the 'exit'. I thought that "pipe:1" sends output to stdout but that does not do anything.

```
var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i',filename,'-af','silencedetect=n=-40dB:d=0.2', '-f', 'null','-y', 'pipe:1' ]);

ffmpeg.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log('ffmpeg2 PARENT got message:', JSON.stringify(data));
});

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('ffmpeg stdout data = '+JSON.stringify(data) );
});

ffmpeg.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
  console.log('child process exited with code:' + code + ' signal:' + signal);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pipe:1` argument to ffmpeg sends the transcoded data `stdout`.

The output that's shown when you run the command outside of node is sent to `stderr` by default, and you can handle it in your program with:

```
ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('ffmpeg stderr data = '+data );
});
```

Comment: When I run this I get [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Q5dnaj1OUTZ2tMZDhfNS1HbWc/edit?usp=sharing). I am not even sure what I am looking at.

Comment: Figured out that those the base 10 ASCII characters codes of the data.

Comment: Yes, they're the raw stream. You can proceed from here with the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584171/parsing-the-stderr-output-of-node-js-child-process-line-by-line

Comment: Then, how can we differentiate between an error and standard terminal output if both go to stderr?

Comment: @Guig, you can check the exit codes of ffmpeg to see if it succeeded (`0`) or failed (anything else).